# Why does Collections.sort not put these strings in the right order?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I'm a beginner in Java. I don't understand why this code does not work properly. I'm confused. Can someone please explain why. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class HW20 {

    public static ArrayList<String> abc(String ... strings) {

        ArrayList<String> strings1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strings));
        Collections.sort(strings1);
        return strings1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> strings1 = abc("1", "9", "4", " 2", "6", "8", "3", "5", "7", "0");
        System.out.println(strings1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[ 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You also can do import java.util.*; instead of three import statements. I assume you want the output [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]?

Answer (score 5):

Notice that there's a space character in the string `" 2"`. This means that when the strings are being compared, since the ASCII code for a space is lower than the ASCII code for any other numbers, `" 2"` will compare less than all the other strings, which is why it comes first. Removing that space character will cause the strings to come back in (lexicographically) sorted order.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the space in the array where you have `" 2"`.  It is throwing off your sort.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you wanna sort string order by asc
You should change

`Collections.sort(strings1);` -> `Collections.sort(strings1, Collator.getInstance());`

So Colletions utils can understand

Comment: Is this necessary? Isn't that the default behavior?

Comment: @templatetypedef please note that `" 2",` there's 1 space

Comment: No, the default behavior is lexicographic ordering. Like in any other language and as you would expect it. And that will put a space before other characters like that. You will see the same everywhere else when trying to order strings. For example try naming windows files with spaces and let the explorer sort them by name, same behavior.